# QTableView filtering with QSortFilterProxyModel (grouping filters)

Tags: qt, filtering, qtableview

It seems I am not capable of filtering more then one column at once. I think it's common usage when using filters, maybe I'm missing something.

For example, i have 4 columns in my `QTableView`, let's say column `X (string), Y (int), Z (string), Q (string)`. I wish to filter by `filter_1` column `X` and filter by `filter_2` column `Z`. Is it possible to set `QSortFilterProxyModel` filter for more then one column (dynamically), but not all (re implementing `filterAcceptsRow`).

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use setFilterRegExp(), setFilterWildcard(), or setFilterFixedString() methods to set a filter.  An example from QT doc is :

```
proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(QRegExp(".png", Qt::CaseInsensitive,
                                             QRegExp::FixedString));
proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(1);
```

If these methods are not sufficient, according to Qt documentation [customizing proxy models](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/model-view-proxy-models.html#customizing-proxy-models) is designed to be used via inheritance.

> For advanced users,
>   QSortFilterProxyModel can be
>   subclassed, providing a mechanism that
>   enables custom filters to be
>   implemented.

In this case you need to sublass and override filterAcceptsRow() method.

Comment: I tried using subclass and overriding filterAcceptsRow() method, but with that method filters will work on all columns selected in it. I need dynamic method, so i will be able to sometimes filter on X column it self, sometimes X, Y and sometimes X, Y, Z, Q. Will work on it some more and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Check out this example http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/24267-QSortFilterProxyModel-setFilterRegExp-for-more-than-1-column. Do something similar or you can also use filterAcceptsColumn method

Comment: Took some time to implement it into my case, works! Thanks a lot!